# create action for has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have models like this:

```
User
Paper
Subscription
```

As you can see there is `has_many :through` relationship and the `Subscription` stores `:user_id and :paper_id`

Paper has its own controller and its `PapersController#index` action lists all the available papers.

Now the real question

I want to add a "Subscribe" link next to every paper, which means to invoke the

```
SubscriptionsController#create
```

method.

In my PapersController#index

```
<td><%= link_to "Subscribe", subscriptions_path(paper),:method => :post %></td>
```

In my SubscriptionsController#create I have

```
    def create
        @subscription = current_user.subscriptions.build(subscription_params)
        if @subscription.save
          flash[:success] = "Paper Added to Profile"
          redirect_to root_url
        else
          render 'static_pages/home'
        end  
   end
```

When I look into the subscriptions table the :paper_id is nil, how can I get the :paper_id
I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: `link_to` doesn't take a post option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equivalent routes for `link_to "Subscribe", subscriptions_path,:method => :post` is

```
POST   /subscriptions(.:format)                              subscriptions#create
```

So, you have to pass the `paper_id` explicitly. Have a look at [link_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to).

Update your link to `<td><%= link_to "Subscribe", subscriptions_path(paper_id: paper.id),:method => :post %></td>`

And Instead of

```
@subscription = current_user.subscriptions.build(subscription_params)
```

its should be (as `paper_id` is not under subscription namespace, you can access it directly)

```
@subscription = current_user.subscriptions.build({paper_id: params[:paper_id]})
```

Comment: Thank you It worked :) can you please explain me a bit. I am confused here.

Comment: what will happen if the params[:paper_id] comes in as null or blank. I think your code should handle it in a graceful manner.

Comment: And One more question, now I have user_id and paper_id in my Subscription table what is the best way to display the name of the user and name of the paper.

Comment: @Raghu : Yes, this is not a clean way to handle this situation, I have just fixed the issue in the above code.

Comment: @user3404674 : hope it will make some sense now.

Comment: Ok, what do you mean when you say "paper_id is not under subscription namespace" ? Sorry for too much question I am new.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a try with following.

```
def create
        paper = Paper.where(id: params[:id]).first
        @subscription = current_user.subscriptions.push(paper)
        flash[:success] = "Paper Added to Profile"
        redirect_to root_url
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

Recheck your params value from server console or by debugging. I think you may be supply paper as separate parameter like params[:paper_id] but you build  @subscription instance only by subscription_params that is not the value of paper_id. For this purpose modify your create action like this

```
@subscription = current_user.subscriptions.build(subscription_params.marge({:paper_id => params[:paper_id]})
```